# Concourse: Read git resource meta-data

Tags: concourse, concourse-git-resource

I have a concourse pipeline:

```
groups: []
resources:
- name: source-code
  type: git
resource_types: []
jobs:
- name: build
  public: true
  plan:
  - get: source-code
  - task: build
    privileged: true
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source:
          repository: java
          tag: openjdk-8-alpine
      run:
        path: sh
        args:
        - -exc
        - |
          set -e -u -x

          MVN_VERSION=$(cat pom.xml | grep "^    <version>.*</version>$" | awk -F'[><]' '{print $3}')

          **CUSTOM_VERSION = [POM_FILE_VERSION]-build.[NO_OF_COMMITS_IN_BRANCH]** 
      inputs:
      - name: source-code
```

Using Unix commands, I want to create the custom version:

```
CUSTOM_VERSION = [POM_FILE_VERSION]-build.[NO_OF_COMMITS_IN_BRANCH]
```

For **[POM_FILE_VERSION]**, I have found the code:

```
MVN_VERSION=$(cat pom.xml | grep "^    <version>.*</version>$" | awk -F'[><]' '{print $3}')
```

But for **[NO_OF_COMMITS_IN_BRANCH]**, i don't know how get that data from git resource. Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 1):

The Concourse git resource doesn't provide the number of commits in the branch.

I suggest to use something more meaningful like the commit hash, which the Concourse git resource makes available as the `.git/short_ref` file.

If you really need to use the number of commits (but why?), then you need to run the `git` command directly in the Concourse task, for example `git rev-list --count HEAD`.

In the pipeline above, the task is using the `openjdk-8-alpine` Docker image from the `java` repository. If that image contains `git`, then you are all set. If not, I suggest first to see if the `java` repository offers a variation of `openjdk-8-alpine` with git installed. If not, you have to create your own Docker image, based off `openjdk-8-alpine`.

Security note: you have `privileged: true` specified. Probably you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks friend, i'll look into the docker image now, "git" is not there actually. Do you have any idea of how i can return plain "String" e.g. 18.8.8 from the "build" task (which i mentioned in my question) and use it in other task as input ? Actually after generating custom_version, i have to send it to other task which will further create folder on artifact portal and then push my jars.